# android retrofit Hostname not verified

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, retrofit2

I got certificate issued for IP address (Not a common name) and I'm triyng to connect to the server with that certificate.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
ServerRouts service = retrofit.create(ServerRouts.class);
Resp_json> call = service.login(param, user, pw);
```

and I got an error:

```
Hostname 11.8.222.333 not verified:
```

but when I use

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

then everything works.

How to solve that error without turning off hostname verifier?

P.S. My certificate issued for IP (11.8.222.333)

Comment: check it once using rest client if it's working than you need to check issue with retrofit !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I redefined verify method like that ( just copied sources from DefaultHostnameVerifier.java ) and everything works now. I don't know why it didn't work but now it's fine.

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {

                Certificate[] certs;
                try {
                    certs = session.getPeerCertificates();
                } catch (SSLException e) {
                    return false;
                }
                X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) certs[0];
                // We can be case-insensitive when comparing the host we used to
                // establish the socket to the hostname in the certificate.
                String hostName = hostname.trim().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
                // Verify the first CN provided. Other CNs are ignored. Firefox, wget,
                // curl, and Sun Java work this way.
                String firstCn = getFirstCn(x509);
                if (matches(hostName, firstCn)) {
                    return true;
                }
                for (String cn : getDNSSubjectAlts(x509)) {
                    if (matches(hostName, cn)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;

            }
        });


private String getFirstCn(X509Certificate cert) {
        String subjectPrincipal = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().toString();
        for (String token : subjectPrincipal.split(",")) {
            int x = token.indexOf("CN=");
            if (x >= 0) {
                return token.substring(x + 3);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what is getFirstCn(x509) method here

Comment: I get a crash from this code: **AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.igor.mobile, PID: 30362
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array**

Answer (score 2):

The default `HostNameVerifier` for `OkHttpClient.Builder` is `okhttp3.internal.tls.OkHostnameVerifier`. It appears that this verifier does not match hostname against common name in peer's certificate, but only against subject alternative names. This behavior is by design and not a bug - look at this issue: https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4966

Two options solve it:

1. If you want to continue using the `OkHostnameVerifier`, you should make sure your server certificate contains Subject Alternative Name (s). At least repeat the common name in the SAN. I found this gist helpful in doing so: https://gist.github.com/croxton/ebfb5f3ac143cd86542788f972434c96
2. If you cannot control server certificate, you can use an alternative HostNameVerifier implementation which also matches against certificate's CN. The one in @Rainmaker's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41543384/978164) will do. I also found `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier` in Apache's `httpclient` package to work fine and its probably a more through implementation.

```
// instantiate and configure your OkHttpClient.Builder and then:
builder.hostnameVerifier(new org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier());
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is the incorrect answer and it is just a **short-term fix** to avoid getting an error.
I suggest the following solution if you do not need HTTPS exactly:

1. Using HTTP instead of HTTPS
2. Adding the URL to the network_security_config.xml file and place it in the res/xml/ directory
3. In the manifest file add the following attribute to the application tag

   <application
   ...
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ..>

Comment: This is fine for local dev. I would not recommend for prod.